# Disabled link button still submitting in asp.net webform

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to disable a link button to prevent the user from submitting several times.

I've seen many questions like this here on SO, most people suggest the following javascript:

`button.disabled = true` or `button.disabled = 'disabled'`

Which indeed disables the button (the button is greyed out), but the problem is that it's still clickable, and still submits!!

Here is my stripped down code:

`function ValidateButton(button){

   // some other code

   button.disabled = true;

   button.value = 'Processing...';

}`

`<asp:LinkButton Text="Submit" ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" onclick="btnSubmitRow_Click" OnClientClick="return ValidateButton(this);"/>`

1. Why is the button still clickable, and submits after being disabled ?
2. The button text is still "Submit" not "Processing...', why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `LinkButton` control is rendered as an `a` element, and that doesn't have a `disabled` attribute or a `value` attribute.

The code that you have works for a `Button` control that renders as an `input type="button"` or `input type="submit"`, but not for a link. To make it look disabled, you would change it's color, and to prevent it from submitting you would return false from the client side click event handler. Use the `innerHTML` attribute to change the text of the link.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, disabling the link button does not prevent it from sending the request, you should remove the event from the link button when disabling it.
sometimes i replaced the link button with a label that have the same text.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent postback add a `return false` to your `ValidateButton` function when you decide the button should be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

add this to `ValidateButton`:

```
button.onclick = function(){return false;};
```

Answer (score 0):

If the button is still clickable and the value never changes to "Processing..." then are you sure you're targeting the button correctly?

You might try targetting the button by id instead:

```
document.getElementById("btnSubmit ").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("btnSubmit ").value = 'Processing...';
```

Then you'll know for sure that you're manipulating the right element.

You could alternately script a change to the form's submit event.  Set the onSubmit() function to something like `return false;` - this way the user can't put the cursor into a form field and submit it by hitting enter, which circumvents the button anyhow.

Answer (score -1):

You could disable the LinkButton as usual (either client-side or server-side) and you would have to modify your JavaScript to only do work if the button/link is not disabled. So in your case:

```
<asp:LinkButton Text="Submit" ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClientClick="return ValidateButton(this);"></asp:LinkButton>
```

And in your client-side code:

```
function ValidateButton(button){
    if (!button.disabled) {
        // do work here
    }
}
```

If the client-side onClick function returns false, then the postback will never happen.